# R function to reverse a survey item produces NULL

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I'm still new to writing my own functions. As an exercise and because I use it alot, I want to write a flexible function to easily reverse survey response scales. This is what I came up with:

```
 rev_scale = function(var, new_var, scale){
  for (i in 1:length(abs(var))){
    new_var[i] = scale-abs(var[i])+1
  }
}
```

#### Info on code

- var = variable I want to reverse.
- new_var = new column with the reversed variable
- scale = how many points in the scale (eg. 5 for a    5-point scale)

The reason why I use 'abs' instead of just 'var' is that some dataframes also return value-labels, and I only want the values in this function.

#### Question

When applying this new function on a variable, R returns "NULL". However, if I run the for-loop separately, with the arguments 'imputed', my new variable is properly reversed.
Any ideas on what is happening here?

Thanks in advance!

*### Example of the (working) for-loop with arguments 'imputed' ###*

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 4))
df$var = c(1,2,3,4)

for (i in 1:length(abs(df$var))){
  df$var_rev[i] = 4-abs(df$var[i])+1
}
df$var_rev
```

OUTPUT:
[1] 4 3 2 1

Comment: Can you provide code for the situation where your function does not work? I suspect the problem might be that you set `new_var` as an argument to the function. However, it is not an argument, it is the function's result/output. If you want to apply the function like this `df$var_r <- rev_scale(var=df$var, scale=4)`, it makes no sense to add an argument `new_var` in the function. That said, you don't really need to make a custom function because recoding is so simple. For a 4-step Likert item just do: `df$var_r <- 5 - df$var`

Answer (score 0):

R does not use reference-variables (think pointers)*. So your `new_var` outside of your function does not get updated when refered to inside a function. Instead, R creates *a new copy* of `new_var` and updates that.

You should instead *return* the new value from your function. I.e.

```
rev_scale = function(var, scale){
  res <- vector('numeric', length(var))
  for (i in 1:length(abs(var))){
    res[i] = scale-abs(var[i])+1
  }
  return(res)
}
```

Also note that I have removed `new_var` from the function's arguments. In other words, I have completely separated the functions input-arguments from its output.

The reason you get a `NULL` from the function is that in R, all functions returns *somethings*. If not specified, the function will return the last value of the last statement, except when the last statement is a control structure (ifs, loops) - then it defaults to a `NULL`.

`*` There are a couple of exceptions and work-arounds, but I will not go into that here.

**Edit:**

As benimwolfspelz noted, you do not need to explicitly iterate over each element in `var`, as R does this implicitly. Your entire function could be reduced to:

```
rev_scale = function(var, scale) {
  scale-abs(var)+1
}
```

Secondly, in your for-loop, your can simplify `length(abs(var))` to `length(var)` as `abs(var)` does not change the length of the vector.